# Custom Slide Timings with jquery Slideshow plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm using the plugin found here:

http://hostingcouponz.com/jquery-showcase-banner-portfolio/

The interval time between slides is set here:

```
 interval = setInterval(function() {
     auto_number = slider_control.children(controlTabString+".active").prevAll(controlTabString).length+1;
    if (auto_number === slider_control_tab.length) auto_number = 0;
    slider_control_tab.eq(auto_number).trigger('autonext');
}, 5000);
```

I'd like to set a different interval for only the first slide - but am a little stuck.

Is there a simple fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't love the way this is setup, this is the easiest to understand way of translating your current code.

```
 interval = setTimeout(doInterval, 10000); //different numbers, first time

    function doInterval() {
         auto_number = slider_control.children(controlTabString+".active").prevAll(controlTabString).length+1;
         if (auto_number === slider_control_tab.length) auto_number = 0;
         slider_control_tab.eq(auto_number).trigger('autonext');
         interval = setTimeout(doInterval, 5000); //different numbers, subsequent times
    }
```